# Python regex for matching a substring with maximum 1 space

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex which will match a substring with at least one alphabet, one number, max 1 space and string length of 7.

Here is what I have come up with until now:

```
r'\b(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d\s]{7}(?!=[ ]{2,})\b'
```

Examples

```
1. "abc 12 3 vha bnf1254"
2. "abc 123 vha ss1234"
```

Expected outputs:

```
1. ["bnf1254"]
2. ["abc 123", "123 vha", "ss1234"]
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with something like https://regex101.com/? It makes it much more user-friendly to tweak regex patterns

Comment: It would be clearer to give us multiple string samples and expected output. But based on the description and making assumptions, I'm guessing you're looking for something like this: `[\da-z]*[a-z][\da-z]* ?[\da-z]*\d[\da-z]*|[\da-z]*\d[\da-z]* ?[\da-z]*[a-z][\da-z]*`. See https://regex101.com/r/lwYbfk/1

Comment: Added examples.

Comment: `'ss1234'` doesn't have a length of 7. How is it an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Edited for was adding examples:

```
import re

test_strings = [
    "abc 12 3 vha bnf1254",
    "abc 123 vha ss1234"
]

pattern = r'(?=(([a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*\s?[a-zA-Z]*\d*[a-zA-Z]*|[a-zA-Z]*\d*\s?[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)))'

for input_str in test_strings:
    matches = [match.group(1).strip() for match in re.finditer(pattern, input_str) if len(match.group(1)) == 7]
    print(matches)
```

output will this:

```
['bnf1254']
['abc 123', '123 vha', 'ss1234']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting both "abc 123" and "123 vha" in your second example, we have to assume you're looking for overlapping patterns.  If we do include overlapping patterns, there would be more eligible entries than what you are expecting.

```
import re

pattern  = r"(?=[^ ]{7}|[^ ] [^ ]{5}|[^ ]{2} [^ ]{4}|[^ ]{3} [^ ]{3}|[^ ]{4} [^ ]{2}|[^ ]{5} [^ ])"
pattern += r"(?=.{0,6}[a-zA-Z])"
pattern += r"(?=.{0,6}\d)"
pattern += r"(?=([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{6}))[a-zA-Z0-9]"

tests = ["abc 12 3 vha bnf1254",
         "abc 123 vha ss1234"]

for test in tests:
    print( [test[m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(pattern,test)] )


['ha bnf1', 'a bnf12', 'bnf1254']
['abc 123', '123 vha', 'vha ss1', 'ha ss12', 'a ss123']
```

In order to support overlapping patterns, I used a single character extract with a capturing group within a lookahead for all 7.

The pattern is composed of four parts:

- `r"(?=[^ ]{7}|[^ ] [^ ]{5}|`...`|[^ ]{5} [^ ])"` covers the "maximum one space" requirements by looking ahead for substrings that have either no spaces or a single space at the second, third, fourth or fifth position. (I assumed you didn't want the space to be first or last)
- `r"(?=.{0,6}[a-zA-Z])"` covers the "at least one letter" requirement by looking ahead for a letter within the next 7 characters (i.e. a letter after 0,1,2,3,4,5 or 6 characters)
- `r"(?=.{0,6}\d)"` covers the "at least one digit" requirement using the same approach as letters
- `r"(?=(.[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{6}))[a-zA-Z0-9]"` looks ahead for 7 eligible characters, capturing them in a group, but only matches the first one so that overlaps are processed.

As you can see in the results, 'ha bnf1' and 'a bnf12' fit all your requirements so they are selected.  Same thing for 'vha ss1' and 'ha ss12'.

If we went with non-overlapping patterns, then '123 vha' would not be selected and 'ha bnf1' would be selected before 'bnf1254' with which it overlaps.

```
pattern  = r"(?=[^ ]{7}|[^ ] [^ ]{5}|[^ ]{2} [^ ]{4}|[^ ]{3} [^ ]{3}|[^ ]{4} [^ ]{2}|[^ ]{5} [^ ])"
pattern += r"(?=.{0,6}[a-zA-Z])"
pattern += r"(?=.{0,6}\d)"
pattern += r"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{5}[a-zA-Z0-9]"
for test in tests:
    print(re.findall(pattern,test) )

['ha bnf1']
['abc 123', 'vha ss1']
```